# Is it possible to create a dialog which only blocks its parent?

Tags: c#, winforms

My application has a global menu and some MDI children (in a Tab Manager). Each MDI Child should behave separately. I would like an MDI child to be able to show a modal dialog that only blocks its parent, and not the other MDIs in the application

When I display a modal form from an MDI child, all MDI children are blocked. **How can I create a dialog that only blocks input on its parent?**

Comment: Downvoters, you may find the question stupid but you can at least give an idea or a comment. Thanks.

Comment: This question really sounds like a  'give me codez' as it's currently written, with no code or attempt displayed. Please explain exactly what it is you are asking (as specific as possible/required), as well as what you have tried. Think of it this way, we're not there to see what's wrong, we're here **trying to**. We can't do that without background info, as well as a little idea of what you're trying to achieve! (**please note** *I have not downvoted or upvoted on this question* )

Comment: The last time I looked 'modal' __means__ blocking other forms.

Comment: @TaW : Yes ! But is it possible to have a design that will block only the window which opened the modal form and not the others ? Thanks.

Comment: have you googled any examples of `MDI, Parent vs Owner` this sounds do able but without seeing any coded effort it's hard to determine what you're really wanting to do..

Comment: A Dialog tells the user to "handle this now".  Your UI would go against that.  You can hack at it by putting your form's controls inside a panel, and when you want to show a "dialog" hide the panel, then show a new user control inside the child form.  Any attempt to use ShowDialog won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **disable** the opening Form instead of making the modal child truly modal..

You can try this: Open the 'modal' children with

```
this.Enabled = false;
FormDlg yourModalChildForm= new FormDlg(this);
yourModalChildForm.Show();
```

In the constructor write :

```
    Form myParent;

    public FormDlg(Form myParent_)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myParent = myParent_;
    }
```

And in the FormClosed write:

```
  private void FormDlg_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
  {
      myParent.Enabled = true;
  }
```