# Preventing user to click a Tab Page

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

I haven't found a solution yet related to this problem. I just to disable other tabpages in my Winforms TabControl when a certain tabpage is open. So not hiding them but disable the function to open them when one clicks a tab page. It just should be displayed grey. Is this possible? I've read something about a "Selected" event but don't know how to use that.

Comment: How will you re-enable the other pages?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418006/how-can-i-disable-a-tab-inside-a-tabcontrol

Comment: This link didn't help me. I don't know how to use the code the right way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Selecting` event:

Create a class level variable:

```
int lockedPage = -1;
```

If it is set to the index of a `TabPage` you can select it but you can't leave it, i.e. you can't select any other page.

```
private void tabControl1_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (lockedPage >= 0 && e.TabPageIndex != lockedPage) e.Cancel = true;

}
```

If you set `lockedPage = 0;` you prevent the user from leaving the 1st page etc..

To re-enable the selection of other pages set it to `-1`

Comment: How to use that when I want that every other tab is disabled when one certain is enabled?

Comment: Loop through all tabpages when one is disabled and disable them

Comment: I have expanded the code a little. You need to include some code to set the flag variable to be less than zero..

Comment: @Jackson30 Your "one" active tab is *acting* more like a dialog box.

Comment: He can't find tabControl1_Selecting

Comment: What is the name of your `Tab` control? Not  `tabControl1` ?

Comment: It's tabControl2. So I changed it to tabControl2. I'm calling it from a method of another form. I've placed it in my form1 (That works) but when I call it with form1.tabControl2_Selecting he doesn't recognize it

Comment: To access it from another form you need a public reference to it as usual.. Many, many posts explain how to do that..!

Comment: Yes I made it public and try to call it with form1.tabControl2_Selecting(this, eventArgs.Empty) like usual but this time it doesn't work. He can't find the arguments.

Comment: Um. No! The selected event should stay with the Tab control!! If you need to control the lock from another form you need to access the `lockedPage`variable. And since it is in the form1 you need 1) to make it public, best a public property: `int lockedPage {get; set;}` 2) a reference to form1 in form2. One common way it to pass the form in the constructor..[Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28968575/is-it-possible-to-create-a-dialog-which-only-blocks-its-parent/28969335#28969335) for an example of this technique! If you make `lockedPage` a property, don't forget to intialize it!

Comment: Ok I tried that now but I need to call the method somehow from my second form. Otherwise I can't call the event. I even tried it with (null,null) and I get a nullreference exception

Comment: No, you do not call events. __Never__. (Almost). __Not here__!! (You __couldn't__ create the __necessary__ parameters!) The event happens by itself, that is by the user clicking at some tab.. Make sur it is hooked up in the events tab of the property window!

Comment: Ok that will be the problem. How to do that?

Comment: Not a problem, but a __very basic__ thing. Try Google for any amount of nice tutorials: "C# hooking up events". Or explore the parperty tab for the event tab (with the arrow) by yourself..

Comment: Ok I found it! It works! Thank you very much. That was the thing I was looking for!